# Running Model on both GPUs and CPUs

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, transformer, gpu, hpc

I have access to a hpc node, of 3 GPU and maximum of 38 CPU. I have a transformer model which I run of a single GPU at the moment, I want to utilize all the GPUs and CPUs.
I have seen couple of tutorial on Dataparrallel and DistributedDataParallel. They only mentioned how to  use multiple GPUs.

My questions are:

1. Do I use  Dataparallel or DistributedDataParallel
2. How do I adapt my code run on the GPUs and CPUs simultaneously. Perhaps if I can get a tutorial link.
3. How to do I get the device ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I did use DistributedDataParallel according to PyTorch documentation DataParallel is usually slower than DistributedDataParallel therefore it is recommended since DistributedDataParallel works for both single- and multi-machine training.
2. Tutorial [Comparison between DataParallel and DistributedDataParallel](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html#comparison-between-dataparallel-and-distributeddataparallel)
3. Another Tutorial [Multi-GPU Examples](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/parallelism_tutorial.html)
4. Solution [LITDataScience's answer - How to find the nvidia GPU IDs for pytorch cuda run setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72415800/how-to-find-the-nvidia-gpu-ids-for-pytorch-cuda-run-setup)